Converting DVD files into MKV conserving audio and subtitle tracks with ffmpeg
I have some VOB files that I want to convert into MKV conserving all audio and subtitle tracks, if possible automatically and with a single command. I do not want to use anything but ffmpeg (clever_ffmpeg_gui gets stuck and I do not want other programs like MakeMKV).
I tried:
ffmpeg -i "concat:VTS_01_1.VOB|VTS_01_2.VOB|VTS_01_3.VOB|VTS_01_4.VOB" -vcodec libx265 -profile:v main10 -x265-params "level=5.1:high-tier=1:crf=20" -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -acodec aac file.mkv

But this has several problems in the resulting video:

There is no sound (or my player does not render any sound)
The video does not play, stays in 00:00. Only when I wait for some minutes it starts playing. I can seek and see any frame, but it stays static until I wait. This happened to me before with other MPG -> MP4/MKV conversions.
It has only one audio track and no subtitles.


Try concat with a file list...

What do you mean

-f concat list.txt and inside list.txt is something like file '1.vob' file '2.vob' file '3.vob' one file on each line...

To be honest I have never tried this using ffmpeg but here seems to be a nice tutorial: https://www.internalpointers.com/post/convert-vob-files-mkv-ffmpeg

The concatenation is not an issue. I can test with the first file and the same things happen. I have seen a similar tutorial, but will not solve my issues, and also requires manual analysis of the file

Unfortunately you insist on not using anything. If you didn't someone would have suggested Handbrake already that does exactly what you want (and a lot more).

So you mean that ffmpeg cannot do it?

I don't know but I suppose it can. I don't use it.
